# How Do I Access Data from a Google Calendar for a iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, google-calendar-api, xcode9

I'm new to Xcode 9.0 programming.  I'm trying to create an iOS App which will read event data from a Google Calendar and write event data to a Google Calendar.  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement this?

Comment: Start here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/ and here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ios . Did you even google this??

Comment: You can set up a simple iOS application that makes requests to the Google Calendar API using the [quickstart code](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ios) in the documentation. Then, you can refer to the [events resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) for a complete list of resources that you can use to implement your desired function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I got the Google Calendar API to work.